# SQL Server : table making two references to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, associations

I have a `Person` table and also `Stuff` table. `Stuff` could belong to a person and also somebody else (not owner) could use the stuff.

Here is the design:

Person

- Id
- Name

Stuff

- Id
- Name
- OwnerId (not required)
- UserId (not required)

Now altering the table to make the associations:

```
alter table [stuff]
add constraint Stuff2PersonOwner
    foreign key (PersonId)
    references [person] (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

The script above executes fine.

```
alter table [stuff]
add constraint Stuff2PersonUser
    foreign key (UserId)
    references [person] (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

When I execute the script above I get an exception:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Stuff2PersonUser' on table 'Stuff'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

What is the problem here? Why I can't create the second association with `ON DELETE SET NULL`?

Comment: As it said, Specify `ON DELETE NO ACTION` or `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but wouldn't that cause an issue if I delete the person?

Comment: No, the first constraint will handle it

Comment: @Ormoz I am not sure if I am following you: Are you saying that if I specify ON DELETE SET NULL on one association that will also work for the other association?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx) for foreign keys specifies the following limitation:

> The series of cascading referential actions triggered by a single
>   DELETE or UPDATE must form a tree that contains no circular
>   references. No table can appear more than one time in the list of all
>   cascading referential actions that result from the DELETE or UPDATE.
>   **Also, the tree of cascading referential actions must not have more
>   than one path to any specified table.** Any branch of the tree is ended
>   when it encounters a table for which NO ACTION has been specified or
>   is the default.

The highlighted sentence describes what is happening.  `Stuff` is being reached by two potential paths when a `Person` is deleted -- one for each of the columns.  Hence, SQL Server does not allow the second foreign key relationship with this option.